# some body help me with this index.xhtml

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping, servlet-3.0

Here I'm trying to make Java Web MVC using Spring/Hibernate. Some process its generated from net beans wizard.

**index.xhtml**

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
  <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  Sistem Informasi Sekolah
  <br />

  <h:link outcome="welcomePrimefaces" value="Primefaces welcome page" />
  <h:form>
    <p:commandButton action="#{indexController.moveToPageSiswa}" value="Informasi Siswa" />
  </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

But the result justs shows

`Sistem Informasi Sekolah`

and its not showing the button.

It happens after I'm trying to modify the code.